# How to get x86-64 debug registers working to set breakpoint from parent process?

Tags: c, x86-64, hardware, breakpoints, ptrace

I've been trying to set dr0, dr6 and dr7 x86-64 CPU registers for a while in order to add a hardware breakpoint to a child process. However, I never get a SIGTRAP from the child after resuming it.

I've set debug registers the following way :
**DR0** -> The address of the function I wan't the child process to break on.
**DR6** -> 0. I read it must be null when setting a breakpoint/watchpoint.
**DR7** -> 0x701. That means I set the following flags to 1 : reserved_10, dr0_local, LE and GE.

First thing that surprised me, when I use `ptrace(PTRACE_POKEUSER, ...)` on DR7 field of the user struct, I often get a -1 return code. Do you have any idea of what could cause that issue ? However, when the return code is 0 I won't get the breakpoint to work neither.

My code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DR_OFFSET(dr) ((((struct user *)0)->u_debugreg) + (dr))

pid_t child_pid;

void child_func() {
    printf("CHILD\n");
}

int main() {
    if(child_pid) {
        waitpid(child_pid, NULL, 0);
        struct user_regs_struct regs = {};
        ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, child_pid, NULL, &regs);
        printf("BREAKPOINT : RIP -> %llx\n", regs.rip);
        printf("POKE DRO : %lx\n", ptrace(PTRACE_POKEUSER, child_pid, DR_OFFSET(0), (void*)&child_func));
        uint64_t dr7 = 0;
        dr7 |= (uint64_t)pow(2, 0) + (uint64_t)pow(2, 8) + (uint64_t)pow(2, 9) + (uint64_t)pow(2, 10);
        printf("POKE DR7 : %lx\n", ptrace(PTRACE_POKEUSER, child_pid, DR_OFFSET(7), &dr7));
        printf("POKE DR6 : %lx\n", ptrace(PTRACE_POKEUSER, child_pid, DR_OFFSET(6), 0));
        printf("PTRACE_CONT : %lx\n", ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child_pid, NULL, NULL));
        printf("WAITPID : %x\n", waitpid(child_pid, NULL, 0));
        memset(&regs, 0, sizeof(regs));
        ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, child_pid, NULL, &regs);
        printf("BREAKPOINT : RIP -> %llx\n", regs.rip);
        ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child_pid, NULL, NULL);
    }
    else {
        ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);
        __asm__("int3");
        child_func();
    }
    return 0;
}

void __attribute__ ((constructor)) premain() {
    child_pid = fork();
}
```

As you can see, I've set a software breakpoint in the child process for it to stop so that I can deal with its user struct.
The result of an execution is the following (when dr7 injection works) :

```
BREAKPOINT : RIP -> 5651726ec2ee
POKE DRO : 0
POKE DR7 : 0
POKE DR6 : 0
PTRACE_CONT : 0
CHILD
WAITPID : 38af
BREAKPOINT : RIP -> 0
```

The second RIP value (null) means the program did not stop on my hardware breakpoint.

**EDIT** : Thanks to your useful comments this code is working :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DR_OFFSET(dr) ((((struct user *)0)->u_debugreg) + (dr))

pid_t child_pid;

void child_func() {
    printf("CHILD\n");
}

int main() {
    if(child_pid) {
        waitpid(child_pid, NULL, 0);
        struct user_regs_struct regs = {};
        ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, child_pid, NULL, &regs);
        printf("BREAKPOINT : RIP -> %llx\n", regs.rip);
        printf("POKE DRO : %lx\n", ptrace(PTRACE_POKEUSER, child_pid, DR_OFFSET(0), (void*)&child_func));
        uint64_t dr7 = 0;
        dr7 |= (uint64_t)pow(2, 0) + (uint64_t)pow(2, 8) + (uint64_t)pow(2, 9) + (uint64_t)pow(2, 10);
        printf("POKE DR7 : %lx\n", ptrace(PTRACE_POKEUSER, child_pid, DR_OFFSET(7), &dr7));
        printf("POKE DR6 : %lx\n", ptrace(PTRACE_POKEUSER, child_pid, DR_OFFSET(6), 0));
        printf("PTRACE_CONT : %lx\n", ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child_pid, NULL, NULL));
        printf("WAITPID : %x\n", waitpid(child_pid, NULL, 0));
        memset(&regs, 0, sizeof(regs));
        ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, child_pid, NULL, &regs);
        printf("BREAKPOINT : RIP -> %llx\n", regs.rip);
        ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child_pid, NULL, NULL);
    }
    else {
        ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);
        __asm__("int3");
        child_func();
    }
    return 0;
}

void __attribute__ ((constructor)) premain() {
    child_pid = fork();
}
```

```
BREAKPOINT : RIP -> 5640849712e1
POKE DRO : 0
POKE DR7 : 0
POKE DR6 : 0
PTRACE_CONT : 0
WAITPID : 3cc9
BREAKPOINT : RIP -> 564084971400
CHILD
```

Comment: Probably not related, but `pow` is for floating-point exponentiation and isn't suitable for integer calculations.  For integer powers of 2, just use left shift: `1 << 9` instead of `pow(2,9)`.  For integer powers of other integer bases, C doesn't have a standard function so you just write a loop (or use [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)).

Comment: Yes you are right. I definitely should have used bit shifting. However I know I get the value I want and the issue doesn't come from here.

Comment: @NateEldredge: To match the cast to `uint64_t` and allow shift counts up to 63, you want `1ull << n`.  But yeah, `double pow(double, double)` is insane for what could have been purely an integer constant expression.  That introduces the possibility of rounding error + truncation giving `2^n - 1` instead of the desired `2^n`.  HellDiner: I'd still fix the code so future readers aren't distracted by that, even if you have checked the `dr7` value you get and it had bits in the right places.

Comment: `ptrace(PTRACE_POKEUSER, child_pid, DR_OFFSET(7), &dr7));`: Should be `(void *)dr7` not `&dr7` right?  `PTRACE_POKEUSER` takes as its argument the value to be poked, not a pointer to it.  So you are setting `dr7` to some address on your stack.

Comment: I assume this test program was compiled with optimization disabled?  `void child_func()` is missing `__attribute__((noinline))`.

Comment: I changed dr7 to `1 + (1 << 8) + (1 << 9) + (1 << 10)` and `ptrace(PTRACE_POKEUSER, child_pid, DR_OFFSET(7), dr7));`. Now I get no error on the ptrace call. But still not the breakpoint hit.

Comment: I'd recommend taking your working code and self answering your question with an answer.

Comment: I think you reposted the same code for your solution as your original question. Did you do the wrong copy and paste?